# Pastespecial in VBA code returns syntax error

Tags: excel, vba

When attempting to execute the code below i am displayed a syntax error

```
Sub collate3()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim shAry
Range("A6:AZ7000").ClearContents
    For i = 2 To 3
        Set sh1 = Workbooks(i).Sheets("DNY") 'Edit sheet name
        shAry = Array(sh1)
            For j = LBound(shAry) To UBound(shAry)
                Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j + 1)
                lr = shAry(j).UsedRange.Rows.Count
                shAry(j).Range("L5:S" & lr).EntireRow.Copy _
                sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Next
    Next
    Range("A:A,C:K,Q:R,T:Z").Delete
End Sub
```

The error occurs when i include `sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

It works fine if i do `sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(6)` however i only need values

Comment: If I remove the underscore after `Copy _` I receive no errors, but this wouldn't work for your other scenario either.  If you still have the problem try adding `EntireRow` like this `sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(6).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: @Portland Runner - I did give that a go before however i still get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get it to compile, you need to add () around your .PasteSpecial argument. Like this:

```
shAry(j).Range("L5:S" & lr).EntireRow.Copy _
sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(6).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

However, I don't think that's what you want to achieve. Range.Copy method is expecting a *Destination* parameter as its argument, not a PasteSpecial *Action*.

What is the purpose of the (6)?

Comment: Why would i just want it to compile? Does compilation mean a working solution? The purpose of (6) is the row the copied records start from.

Comment: For me, your code doesn't even compile -> it's a syntax error.

Comment: Yes it does have a syntax error but i don't just want to compile it. I would like it to work.

Comment: Please can you be more explicit about "you want it to work"? If you delete the _ is that not good enough for you? By the way, instead of (6) it might be more explicit to put .Rows(6). Do you need EntireRow in there as well that @Portland Runner already suggested?

Comment: I would like `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` as intended. The reason i have `EntireRow` is because i need the entire row of values across multiple columns. As mentioned even when i do remove the underscore, it still returns an error.